# When does my bounty end exactly?

Tags: support, bounties

Just a small question about bounty ending. [My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934518/wanted-offline-ide-for-developing-html-javascript-on-android-tablet) has the following message:

> This question has an open bounty worth +50 reputation from Kees ending tomorrow

Does this mean I have to **award** the bounty *today* or can I award it *tomorrow* as well?

Comment: great question. Those vague time specifications are annoying...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hover over the word "tomorrow". The mouse tooltip will show you the exact time the bounty will expire. You need to award it before then.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! The discover-ability of this feature should be better, with a small line under the word or something.

Comment: @Kees yeah. It's a general rule: Wherever a date or time span is mentioned, you can hover over it to get the exact value.

Comment: Yup, or a reputation score. Or a badge count. Or lots of other things in the interface.